# Android sliding between layouts as the ImageButton is held

Tags: android, android-layout, slider

I have an image and I've included it as an ImageButton (but ImageView would probably be fine as well). It looks like soemthing that is to be dragged up, in order to switch to the Settings interface. I've been researching this for days, looking at lots of pages on the question (many of them concerning ViewPager), but none of them was clear - some of them say "use class X", others just assume I know tons of things I don't. There was a few ones that actually worked, but they were horizontal. The vertical ones I found were incomprehensible and unexplained. Can anyone explain it in an *understandable* manner, please?

Basically what I need is:

- I have layout.xml and layout2.xml;
- there is an image on the bottom part of layout.xml;
- as the user slides that image up, layout2 comes from the bottom;
- If the user went past 50% (or something like that) when he released the image, it slides all the way up. If the user was at or before 50%, it goes all the way back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a built-in widget called a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) to do just that.  In your case, the image at the bottom of layout.xml would be considered the "handle," and layout2.xml would be the "content."  The handle can be any type of widget, be it a Button, ImageButton, ImageView, etc.  If you touch or slide the handle, it will slide to cover the screen as you described.

The Android documentation in the link above explains it pretty well, but I can try to explain a bit more if you have specific questions

Comment: Okay, that worked. However, the button remains at the top of the next slide, I don't want that. I want it to completely switch to the next slide, so that the user can return from a Back button instead.

Comment: Ok, I solved that by setting the button's image to one with 1 pixel height and color that matches the background. Certainly not a perfect solution, but anything more is not time-efficient, given the time I already spent on that.